# UWP access existing page instance

Tags: c#, class, uwp, navigation, instance

i'm developing an UWP app with `NavigationView` for navigation between `Page`.

One `ConnectionPage` is for opening and managing an socket connection, so there are methodes like `SendCommand` and `Receive` and so on. The other `CameraPage` needs to access this methodes. If i navigate to `ConnectionPage` an instance of this class is createt as normal, if i navigate to `CameraPage` this class is created, everything as it should be.

My question now ist, how can i use the connection and methodes of the `ConnectionPage` in my `CameraPage`?

**MainPage.xaml.cs navigation**

```
    private void NavView_Navigate(NavigationViewItem item) {
        switch (item.Tag) {
            case "home":
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage)); break;
            case "connection":
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ConnectionPage)); break;
            case "camera":
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(CameraPage)); break;
        }
    }
```

My approach in previous projects was to pass the instance of a `Connection` class to the constructor of classes that needs it.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate from a page, the page is removed from memory (as long as there is not anything holding it there, in which case you probably get a memory leak).

The correct way to solve this problem is to create a separate class that will contain the methods you require and will be available to both pages - it could either be a `static` class or better a singleton class (class with only one instance). In any case, to have a single state object available to multiple pages, you will have to separate it out of the pages into a new class.

Comment: That is a goot idea for my connection object and the associated methods. Have you also an idea how i can a access an `ListView` based on an `ObservableCollection` in my `ConnectionPage` from the `CameraPage` ?

Comment: You can use the same approach for a collection property as well :-). Actually the recommended approach for UWP apps is to build MVVM architecture where you have View Model classes which are built for the purpose of holding data which are suitable for presentation

Comment: And the ViewModel classes should be static so they can be accessd by all views right?

Comment: Well, if you use a MVVM framework like MVVM Light or Prism, the view models are either singletons (so are accessible from a service locator) or are maintained in the navigation stack. Even better solution might be to create a singleton service that will provide the data. Singleton is not static, but it is a normal class which has just one single instance. The advantage is that the singleton can implement interfaces including INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Look here for info on Singleton - http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx